# How to monitor Spring Integration int-jdbc:outbound-gateway progress for long queries

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

We have an **int-jdbc:outbound-gateway** doing a long query ( several minutes ) and we would like to **monitor** that effectively it's doing something, because sometimes our app hangs.

How can we do that ?

Comment: The Spring Integration JDBC is fully based on the Spring JDBC (`JdbcTemplate` to be precisely), which, in turn, is fully based on the standard JDBC. So, if you know the way to monitor regular `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`, the same tricks can be applied to the `int-jdbc:outbound-gateway`

Comment: nop, I dont know how to monitor regular PreparedStatement.executeQuery